# How to get the name of an element that invoked an action using IInterceptor from Castle.DynamicProxy

Tags: c#, reflection, aop, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

Pretty much what I'm trying to do is an aspect using the `IInterceptor` interface from the `Castle.DynamicProxy` namespace for logging certain element actions and save them to a file.

The implementation I have looks as describe below.

The interface type actions I'm intercepting look like this:

```
public interface IPageElement
{
   bool Visible { get; }
   void Select();
   ...
}
```

I have a class that its function is to serve as a factory for creating objects of type `IPageElement`. So, every time a factory method is called, I returned a proxy element by using `CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<T>`, this way:

```
return ProxyGenerator()
   .CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<IPageElement>(
      elementToProxy,
      new MyInterceptor(elementToProxy));
```

As you my guess, `MyInterceptor` class implements the `IInterceptor` interface from `Castle.DynamicProxy`. So, what I'd like to know is how to get the name of that `IPageElement` object that is being intercepted.

I've managed to get the method it calls, the params (if any), etc. by using the `IInvocation` parameter that Intercept method has:

```
invocation.Method; // for the method
invocation.Arguments;  // for the arguments of the method
```

Tried other of the methods/properties `IInvocation` has, but not luck.

Comment: What is "the name of that IPageElement object", your interface has no name? If you want the name of the class implementing your interface, you've got the elementToProxy passed into your interceptor, or you could use `IInvocation.InvocationTarget` and just call `GetType().Name`.

Comment: hey @JonathonRossi in this case, I want the name of the element that's of type `IPageElement`. i.e.: `public IPageElement myElement { get; set; }` so, when i call `myElement.Select()` in my interceptor, I'd like to get 'myElement' as a string value.

Comment: Oh, you want the variable name holding the reference to the element object. DynamicProxy can only do stuff you can also do with normal code, so it isn't possible unless the class with the `myElement` property returned an `IPageElement` that captured that property name and stored it, which could then be used when any of the members are called.